# Trigger required to insert data

Tags: oracle, plsql, sequences

I am trying to load a column with unique sequence number each time a row of data is insrerted in the table.How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Sequence](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views002.htm), and then use the sequence nextval in your insert statements for the column which you want to have sequential incremented value.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq
INCREMENT BY 1
      START WITH 1
      NOMAXVALUE
      NOCYCLE
      CACHE 10;
```

***`INSERT INTO tab VALUES (seq.nextval, col1, col2, col3);`***

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing like "auto_increment" or "identity" in Oracle,
but if you want auto increment in your column value you can use `Sequence` for the this.

after creating sequence you can use `After Insert Trigger` to insert identical value.
here is trigger example...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER dep_ins_trig 
BEFORE INSERT ON <table_name> 
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
  SELECT dept_seq.NEXTVAL
  INTO   :new.id
  FROM   dual;
END;
/
```

This is achieved by `Trigger` and `Sequence` when you want serialized number that anyone can easily read/remember/understand. But if you don't want to manage ID Column (like emp_id) by this way, and value of this column is not much considerable, you can use `SYS_GUID()` at Table Creation to get Auto Increment like this.

```
CREATE TABLE <table_name> 
(emp_id RAW(16) DEFAULT SYS_GUID() PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR2(30));
```

Now your `emp_id` column will accept "globally unique identifier value".
you can insert value in table by ignoring emp_id column like this.

```
INSERT INTO <table_name> (name) VALUES ('name value');
```

So, it will insert unique value to your `emp_id` Column.